# Any english equivalent for "前輩" or "晚輩"?

Tags: translation

It's used in respect for talking to a superior and respectfully, so is there even an english equivalent for it or is it just a special title used for Chinese?

Comment: Is Senpai a widely understood word in English-speaking country?

Comment: @hrzhu, no, it isn't.

Comment: 前辈: predecessor, eldership, master, senior. 晚辈: junior, maybe there are not any equivalent if they are used for **personal pronouns**, like 请前辈赐教 and 晚辈告辞了.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no English equivalent, but there are some equivalents that I know of.

**Senior/Junior**

- older/younger in age or higher/lower in rank.

Examples:

> Bob is the senior developer in our team.

Bob 是我們團隊裡最資深的程序員。

> James is 5 years my junior.

James 比我小五歲。

> Being a senior, I shall take the duty.

作為最資深的人，我應該要拿下這份職務。

**Predecessor**

- person who has a job/position prior to another.

Examples:

> Larry, the new coach of Mickey (I made this up), is way more experienced than his predecessors.

米奇隊的新教練Larry比他的前輩（之前的教練）有經驗多了。

---

Note the subtle difference between predecessor and senior – predecessor has to be someone that **pre-existed** in the setting, whereas senior is someone that **co-exists** in the setting.

Comment: +1 for the answer's accurancy

Answer (score 2):

I would just use 'sir'. A friendly, colloquial way to address an old man is 'old fella'.

你叫我‘前辈 ’, 我已经觉得像史前原人的遗骸了.

When you call me 'old fella',

Answer (score 2):

When addressing a young man, you may say just that:

Young man, could you please help me?